# Gateway Service Prefix

Tags: jhipster

I created a microservice application with Jhipster uaa authentication.  However, when I created my uaa application I called it "auth", which causes issues with the angular app in the gateway (it sets up a route called "auth" and the uaa overrides it, causing login to fail in the gateway app).

Now, I know I can just rename the auth app to "uaa", and things will work, but I like "auth".

So my question is, is there a way to make all the services under the gateway be available under a "services" prefix, so instead of "https://localhost:8080/auth" it would be "https://localhost:8080/services/auth"?

Another option would be to rename the route in the gateway app, but then I need to make sure that as I create my app that none of the new routes conflict with my service names.

I guess a third option would be to move the angular app out of the gateway and put it into it's own service called "app" and then it's "auth" endpoint would be available under "app/auth" and wouldn't conflict with the "auth" service.

I'm not sure which of these options is the most jhipstery way of doing things, and what will break if I choose one of these.

Comment: You could setup static routes for zuul in gateway's application*.yml or provide your own RouteLocator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gateway application, I added the following configuration:

```
zuul:
    prefix: /services
```

Then in the gateway application I did a find/replace on `auth/api` => `services/auth/api`, which should only update some typescript files.

After that everything seems to work fine. I *think* all the backend services find the auth service dynamically based on name, and not by url.